# Dependency httpclient - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, httpclient, build.gradle

my **run** and **debug** buttons in my **Android Studio** are disabled.
I have seen many answers about this but the solution are not correct in my case.
This is my error in my gradle console:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
```

This is my `build.gradle` :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myProjectPackageName"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Zxing libraries Scan
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'

    //Google api books
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-books:v1-rev80-1.21.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'

    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'

    //Facebook Login
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.2'

    // Dependency for Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Have you added any dependencies for `http-client` ?

Comment: no, I have removed okhttpclient. But I didn't use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude `dependencies` inside `build.gradle` files.

```
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-books:v1-rev80-1.21.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' 
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' 
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' 
}
```

Try to exclude it from all configurations.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```

Restart studio and then check again. Or either select app module from drop down menu beside Run button.

Comment: this is again the same problem. But now there is also "ApplicationTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."

Comment: Now the error there isn't but the run and debug buttons are disabled yet.

Comment: @Carlo Restart studio and then check again. Or either select app module from drop down menu beside Run button.